# JQuery - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: jquery

Below is the content of my .aspx page and the "jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js" is in the same location as the .aspx file. When I run the website with debugging, I get the below error. I know I am terribly missing something here. Any clue?

Error :-

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

When I run without debugging, I get the following javascript error:-

```
Line: 10
Error: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

ASPX page content:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script>$(function () { alert('hello') });</script> 

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery UI doesn't inlucde base jQuery. You need to import that before the UI-js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

..fredrik

Comment: +1 also, if you want to download the JQuery files you can use "jquery-1.3.2.min.js" (for the version I am using) locally.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this error we need add [jquery library](http://csharpektroncmssql.blogspot.com/2012/02/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-jquery.html) refernce

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with an ASP website. I was calling Jquery from the min.js link, and resolved the issue by adding Jquery to my project and calling that instead.

This was bad:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I went to that js link in my browser, copied the contents of the page to a file in my project (in the scripts folder) and called it like this instead:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Chrome didnt have any problems using the URL version, but Internet Exploder did for some reason.