# MVC drop down list onchange pass the selected value to the function in the controller and execute it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i am a new in using MVC3 Razor syntax and i have a view that containing a dropdownlist and i want when the user change the value of it , a function in the controller that take selected value as a parameter will be executed automatically.
this is the code that i wrote in the view and i have a compilation error in that line at runtime:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID", "--Select--", new {onchange="FilterdIndex(this.value)"})
```

"DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID" is in the viewBag and this is the function in the controller that i want to call .

```
public ViewResult FilterdIndex(int id)
        {
            var donor = db.DONOR.Include(d => d.BLOOD_GROUP);
            var DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID = from BG in db.BLOOD_GROUP
                            select new
                            {
                                BG.GROUP_ID,BG.GROUP_NAME,
                                Checked=(BG.GROUP_ID==id)
                            };
            ViewBag.DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID = DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID;
            return View(donor.ToList());
        }
```

---

this is  javascript code it executes the controller function correctly but i don't know why after returning to the view i have the error msg in this line  :

```
 DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.error = function () { alert("Error in Getting States!!"); };
```

and this is the whole function:

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      $(document).ready(function () {      
          $("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").change(function () {
              if ($("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").val() != "Select") {
                  var DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE = {};
                  DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.url = '@Url.Action("FilterdIndex", "DONOR")';
                  DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.type = "POST";
                  DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.data = JSON.stringify({ id: $("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").val() });
                  DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.datatype = "html";
                  DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.contentType = "application/json"; 
                  DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.error = function () { alert("Error in Getting States!!"); };
                  $.ajax(DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE);
                }

            });
        });
        </script>
```

and this is the line that causes the exception in "DONOR[dynamic]" file

```
<select AutoPostBack="True" id="DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID" name="DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID" onchange="FilterdIndex(this.value)"><option value="">--Select--</option>
```

Comment: You not using the correct overload - you want [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem},System.String,System.Object%29)

Comment: I checked all 8 overloads of @html.dropdownlist  now and they don't contain this overload

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your comment. Its `@Html.DropDownList("DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID", null, "--Select--", new { onchange="FilterdIndex(this.value)" })` assuming `DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID` is IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` And you have not even shown your script

Comment: i'm sorry i get confused..i tried your code and there is no errors but it doesn't execute the FilterdIndex function

Comment: You need to show your javascript for the `FilterdIndex()` function

Comment: I added it in the question now but still have a problem

Comment: `url: '/Controllers/DONORController/FilterdIndex',` would not work (use you browser tools to dubug your scripts - you would see a 404 error). Use `url: '@Url.Action("FilterdIndex", "DONOR")',` assuming your controller is named `DONORCOntroller`. But that method returns a view and your never do anything with the html it returns anyway (i.e. in the `success` callback)

Comment: when i used debugging tools i found that it is never get into the break point that i located in the beginning of java script code

Comment: Get rid of that obsolete `onchange=...` code and use `$('#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID').change(function() { ..... });` But you have multiple other errors as well - your returning html so it needs to be `dataType: "html",` (not `'json'`) and `BLOOD_GROUP_ID.val()` would never work - it would have been just `BLOOD_GROUP_ID` but with the `.change()` function it will be `$(this).val()`

Comment: I am so sorry , can you take a look to the last update in my answer ?I updated the JS function

Comment: That is not an answer - its another question. You need to delete it and edit your question. And y9ou have not even read my comments - you method returns a view (html) not json!

Comment: I deleted it and updated the question , i'm sorry i forgot to edit it to return a view(html) but after editing it , i still have the same problem

Comment: `if ($("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").val() != "Select") {` is pointless (you don't have a option with `value="Select"`) - You do have one with `<option value="">--Select--</option>` so its simply `if ($(this).val()) {` Just use `DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.data = { id: $(this).val() },` and delete `DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE.contentType = "application/json"; ` Next debug your code (script and server) to determine what the errors are.

Comment: this is the error :0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: That often means your scripts have not been reference correctly. Have you included `jquery-{version}.js`?

Comment: i wrote  : [<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>] and i still have the same exception

Comment: Use Partial View to display that data this link will help you https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you come from a WebForms background where this sort of thing happens all the time with 'Events' this sadly is not how MVC works.

To do what you are trying to do, you will need to create a jquery method for the onchange event of that drop down, then do an async post to your controller.

Have a look at this tutorial which should point you in the right direction
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-dropdownlist-in-mvc-5/

Comment: but the same code line that give me compilation error at run time is also used in the code of the link you gave me....there is no way to call function without using Jquery or i must use it ?

Comment: The example I posted links to the javascript not directly to the controller in your case which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Asmaa Rashad you can try using this way and your action Method which you are calling using Ajax must be of type JsonResult.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("FilterdIndex", "DONOR")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#DONOR_BLOOD_GROUPE_ID").val() },
                success: function (data) {            
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
    </script>
```

For reference you can check this blog [creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/)

Comment: I tried your code but i want my function to return view so i can't change it and i still have this exception :"0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Comment: do you only want to load view . and that view is not tightly coupled

Comment: "0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"             
This Means that your Jquery js files are not getting referenced properly

Comment: I have a view that displsy all donors and i can filter them by their blood group value that selected by dropdownlist ,so i want after choosing specific blood group i call the controller function that filters  and pass them to the view for displaying

Comment: i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158205/jquery-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-object-expected) solution but it isn't work yet

Comment: Use Partial View to display that data this link will help you https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

Comment: have to tried the above link which i have providede